# How to make sure parent block execute first and then child process after calling fork system call

Tags: c++, linux, operating-system, fork, wait

```
int main(){

id_t child1=fork();

if(child1 > 0){

       // want this block to execute completely before child block

}
else if(child1 == 0){

         // want this block to execute after the parent block has executed

}
else{
      perror("Process_failed" );
}
```

Writing the parent's block before forking does the job fine but, I am supposed to do it after the fork.
In the current situation, it sometimes executes the child and sometimes the parent. I know its because of the scheduling method, contact switching etc but, how do i restrict that

Comment: Can you use `std::thread` instead of `fork`? Communicating between threads is much easier then doing it between processes.

Comment: @super actually am doing an assignment and its the requirement to use fork()

Comment: Then I would look into `pthread_mutex` and friends.

Comment: It's not kind. It was a suggestion. To you. You look into it.

Comment: oh I am looking into that

Comment: Easiest way would be not to fork in the first place.  Otherwise have one `wait` for the other to exit, if you're doing a fork/exec.  `pthread_mutex` won't work; after fork the parent and child don't share memory.